# How is unit testing related to code coverage?

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, theory

I know about code coverage being a metric but it is often mentioned in the artciles about unit testing. But when designing the unit tests, I'm trying to write tests for my business logic and do not care much about coverage. What is the relation then?

Answer (score 1):

The thinking goes as follows:

If the code executed when you run your unit tests covers all the code in the class you test (system under test, SUT), you obviously tested all relevant code.
So, a high code coverage of the SUT is a good thing.

But it also can be misleading. Having a 100% code coverage doesn't mean that you actually tested all your business logic. So, concentrating on testing all your business logic is actually the better approach.
If you tested all your business logic, you will have 100% code coverage - or some code in your business logic that is not needed there.
Still, you can use the code coverage to check if you actually have tested all your business logic.

So, to sum up:

1. If you don't have 100% code coverage of your SUT, it strongly suggest that you haven't tested your complete business logic
2. BUT: 100% code coverage doesn't ensure that you tested all of your logic

Answer (score 0):

Literally a "unit test" tests a single unit, or in other words a single component. Thus, unit tests do not necessarily cover business requirements, but rather ensure that *every piece* of a component does what it is meant for. Code coverage measures the percentage of code that has been tested and thus validated. Every piece of code that has not been tested could probably contain defects so a high code coverage result is desired.

Of course unit tests, or rather the frameworks used to implement unit tests can also be used to test more than one component at once. These tests are more like integration tests, though on a very low level.

The relation between code coverage and integration (or business-logic testing) is that if you have a code coverage of 100% you know that every component does what it is supposed to do. But if you want to ensure that the application does what it is supposed to do, a high code coverage is not nearly enough: For this additional integration test (that test more than one component at a time) are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Unit Testing with code coverage on can be a very powerful tool.

For example. When testing a method you can see if you have hit all the logic paths. If not more testing is required. If it is impossible to hit a section of code, you know you can remove it without any side effects.